# How can I betray Ulfric after beating the Stormcloak storyline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My original plan was to join the Stormcloaks and restore Talos worship, but when I would go to kill Tullius, I would kill Ulfric instead, but I can't. Now I'm stuck with a power hungry leader. How do I betray Ulfric?

Comment: Console commands.

Answer (score 3):

You've missed your opportunity.

If you want to "betray" one side or the other, the game gives you the opportunity to start the Jagged Crown quest for one side but ultimately give the crown to the other. Unmodded and/or without cheating, you can only switch sides until the final stages of the Jagged Crown quest, at which point your choice is locked in.

If you want to cheat, you can use [the `setessential` command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) to clear Ulfric's essential flag and kill him (`setessential 0001414D 0` I believe). This will not change anything about the rest of the world and how it sees that you've completed the civil war quest for the Imperials.